# SQL Server 2012 - Trigger failing to commit data locally despite try-catch for sp_testlinkedserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, linked-server

If I make a change to `MyTable` on `MyDatabase`, I want it to delete the contents of `TestTable` on `TestDatabase` on `MYLINKEDSERVER` and reinsert everything from scratch.  To do this, I use a trigger on `MyTable`.  I know this is inefficient but the number of records is less than 10.

In case the linked server is down, I want it to still commit the changes locally to `MyTable` and just send an email alert stating that the linkedserver could not be updated.  I am failing to get the local transaction to commit when the linkedserver is unavailable...  I've tried messing with `XACT_ABORT` but I just get different errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_updatelinkedserver ON MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @linked_server SYSNAME = 'MYLINKEDSERVER'
, @tablename SYSNAME --name of the table calling the trigger so we can send error details in alert eamil

SELECT @tablename = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

BEGIN TRY
    --If linkedserver fails to connect, we do not want the remaining code in the block to run
    --but we do want the original transaction that triggered this to complete.
    EXEC sp_testlinkedserver  @servername = @linked_server

    DELETE FROM MYLINKEDSERVER.TestDatabase.dbo.TestTable

    INSERT INTO MYLINKEDSERVER.TestDatabase.dbo.TestTable
    SELECT *
    FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @subj VARCHAR(1000) = 'TRIGGER FAILURE: ' + @tablename + ': Could not locate linkedserver ' + @linked_server

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients = 'foo@bar.com'
    , @subject = @subj
    , @body = ''
    , @body_format = 'HTML'
    , @profile_name = 'MyEmailProfile'
END CATCH

END
```

Comment: check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql and set SET XACT_ABORT is OFF

Answer (score 0):

Error handling in tsql is complicated and inconsistent. What are you doing wrong? Making assumptions. Here is what Erland says in his lengthy [discussion](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#FinalRemarks) about the topic:

*What is important to understand about triggers is that they are part of the command that fired the trigger, and in a trigger you are always in a transaction, even if you did not use BEGIN TRANSACTION. Sometimes I see people in SQL Server forums ask if they can write a trigger that does not roll back the command that fired the trigger if the trigger fails. The answer is that there is no way that you can do this reliably, so you better not even try. If you have this type of requirement, you should probably not use a trigger at all, but use some other solution.*

So take that last sentence to heart. Note that the link takes you into the middle of the discussion. And there are links at the end of the page that continue to related topics - one of which is about linked servers.

Comment: I got it to the point where it works great if there is an error connecting to the linked server (by using save points) but if there is no error it won't commit at all because it does not like the save point at the beginning.  I'm stumped.